# Cannot locate ECManGen

Tags: c++, windows, event-log

I am wanting to write unmanaged C++ code that reads from and writes to the event log.  I am working with VS2017 and Windows 10.  Everything I have read states that there is a utility ECManGen that is used to create the manifest file that is then run through the message compiler (mc).  I have the latest Windows 10 SDK installed.  According to what I have read, the executable is in the Bin directory under the SDK.  I have scanned my entire drive and have not been able to find the utility.  Has the utility been deprecated for something else?  Is there somewhere I can obtain the utility?  It does not seem to be available for download from Microsoft as a component.

Answer (score 1):

`ecmangen` was removed from the Windows 10 SDK starting with version 10.0.16299.15. If you install an older version of the SDK (side-by-side installation is supported, so you can keep the newer versions as well), it will be available again.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'll give it a try with an older version.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64